# Windows Phone 8: Can't get scrolling div to bounce

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-phone-8, scroll

I understand that you are supposed to be able to get scrolling `div`s to have momentum and bounce at their extreme ends in IE on Windows Phone 8.

I have momentum, but I can't get the `div` to bounce when it reaches the end of a "flick scroll" or swipe-style scroll. Here's the style applied to the `div`. I've tried it with and without the `pan-y` value.

```css
.scrollDiv {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    padding: 13px;
    overflow-x:hidden; 
    overflow-y:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem on Windows Phone 8. In my case this helped:

```css
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
```