# scroll not smooth on table row - windows phone

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8

I am porting an hybrid app from Android to Windows-Phone-8.x.

My WP app on some page is scrolling in a jerky way and is not as smooth as with my android version.

I am just using simple td objects.

How to get a smooth scrolling for windows-phone as well?

I am using html5, phonegap, jquery, jqm.

Here my css:

```
td {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #D3DFEA;    
}
```

I'd prefer not to use external libs.

Comment: Do you do anything special for scrolling? Like using a jQuery method or something? And also, I'd like to know more about "scrolling". Maybe my mistake but I think of vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling, window scrolling (like WP8 panaroma), scrolling (actually expanding) with data etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Compass I use the following mixin to enable smooth scrolling on tablet/mobile. Not sure about windows phone but I assume it's something similar.

```
@mixin overflow-scrolling($x: hidden, $y: auto) {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-x: $x;
    overflow-y: $y;
}
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012358/windows-phone-8-cant-get-scrolling-div-to-bounce) you can make your own combination of prefixes. No way for me to test this atm.

So try to add:

```
-ms-scroll-chaining: none;
-ms-touch-action: pan-y; // depending on direction
-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
```

And let me know if it works ;)